# Why my RSA 2048 Public Key is 294 bytes long?

Tags: java, rsa, public-key

If I do this:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(2048);
KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
Key publicKey = kp.getPublic();
byte [] pubKey = publicKey.getEncoded();
System.out.println("Size: " + pubKey.length);
```

My output value is 294. Shouldn't RSA 2048 output be 256 bytes long?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An RSA key does not consist of random bytes like for instance an AES key; it consists of numbers. The key size of RSA is defined by the modulus, but it also requires a public exponent (usually the fourth number of Fermat or another small prime). So with `getEncoded()` both are returned embedded into an ASN.1 DER encoded byte array. It uses an encoding that is usually present in X5.09 certificates called "SubjectPublicKeyInfo".

If you want to extract the key size, use `((RSAPublicKey) publicKey).getModulus().bitLength()` instead. To have a look at the structure, use `openssl asn1parse` or use an online decoder such as [this](http://lapo.it/asn1js/).

Answer (score 2):

```
  publicKey.getEncoded();
```

This will return an encoded key in a standard format with some overhead (like algorithm identifier).

If you really want the raw key material, you could cast to `RSAPublicKey` and call `getModulus()` and `getPublicExponent()` (gives you `BigInteger`s).